What is expected behavior of CZ in the Hadamard basis?
My understanding was that the CZ gate applies a phase shift in the Hadamard basis that translates to an X gate in the computational basis. However, when I run the simulator, I'm not seeing the effect of the X gate.
(I posted this before realizing there's a dedicated Quantum Computing stackexchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79300498/controlled-z-gate-having-no-effect)
My circuit looks like this:

However, when I measure, I'm getting all the states (|01>, |11>, |10>, |00>) with equal probability instead of seeing the probability of measuring |11> drop out due to the CZ's effect.
In terms of the math, I believe the circuit would look like this:
$$\begin{align*}H^{\otimes2}*CZ*H^{\otimes2}&=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix} * \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}\\&\end{align*}\\ = \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&1\\1&-1&1&1\\-1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
However, when I multiply this by a state vector, I don't see the "bit flipping" behavior that I'd expect from an X gate. For example, $$H^{\otimes2}*CZ*H^{\otimes2} * \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
So, I'm having trouble validating the behavior mathematically to understand what's happening.
How do I complete the math here to understand what the CZ gate is doing?

Assume a single qubit case. Let's first have the qubit in state $|0\rangle$. Application of Hadamard gate changes state of the qubit to $|+\rangle$. Using Z gate, a phase is switched and we have state $|-\rangle$. After that, we again need to apply Hadamard and we get state $|1\rangle$. Effectively, this is equivalent to application of X gate in Z-basis (in other words, it holds that $X=HZH$ or $Z=HXH$).
To see similar behavior in your case, do not apply Hadamards on the control qubit of CZ, rather use identity operator.

I added more context to the problem description.

@devibost: I think you circuit works right. Input to the circuit is 00. A corresponding output is the first column of the matrix which is equally distributed superposition. Since you have Hadamard on control qubit, Z gate works in half cases and in other half it does not. As a result, there is 50% probability that a qubit is flipped and 50% it is not. As a result you see equally distributed superposition as the output.

I'm still not following... Any recommended reading?

@devinbost: Please, try to calculate this matrix: $(I \otimes H) CZ (I \otimes H)$. I think that then you will see that such circuit does what you look for
